# Google docs and Markdown

Tags: markdown, google-docs

Not sure if this question will get accepted but here goes:

I am trying to get Google Docs to accept markdown commands but it isn't happening.  I've followed what Google wants us to do which is to go to `Tools > Preferences` and check automatic detection of Markdown, but it is still not happening.  Anyone else have this issue, and how did you resolve?

I have tried to refresh multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

If you check "Automatically detect Markdown" and then press "OK" then you should be able to use markdown without refreshing the page.

However, it will not work if you paste in markdown --- it has to be actively typed in. One solution is to use a macro to automatically type your markdown in. I used python and the pynput library, and it worked flawlessly:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.type("*a*")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried manually typing and yes, it does work. 